# failing to execute a shell command in windows using WindowsAPI

Tags: c++, winapi

I am trying to execute a ping command in windows via their ShellExecute function.

```
ShellExecute(0, L"open", L"cmd.exe", normToWide(command).c_str(), 0, SW_HIDE);
```

This is how i call the Function.
to get the wide string i use this function

```
std::wstring normToWide(std::string str)
{
    std::wstring str2(str.length(), L' ');
    std::copy(str.begin(), str.end(), str2.begin());
    return str2;
}
```

the command is this:

```
ping 127.9 -l 4 -n 300 > output.txt
```

Although the ip is invalid it should not matter as output.txt should still be populated with some sort of error message at hte least. What is going on with my function?

I expected there to be a output.txt file with the output of the command
I also tried hardcoding my command to make sure it was not a widestr issue

Comment: Are you passing the `/C` argument to `cmd.exe` in the `command` string variable *before* ping? Why aren't you just executing `ping.exe` directly instead of `cmd.exe`?

Comment: no i am not passing the /c argument, i did not know ping.exe was a thing honestly. cmd.exe made more sense

Comment: what is the return value? what does GetLastError have to say?

Comment: Well ping is not a built in command of `cmd.exe` so it's not going to know what to do with it. Probably just best to execute `ping.exe` directly though.

Comment: adding /C fixed it. Can you explain what the /C flag does?

Comment: It *"Carries out the command specified by string and then terminates"* - see `cmd.exe /?` for all options.

Comment: Running `ping.exe` directly wouldn't allow the redirection would it? That's a shell thing.

Comment: @NeilButterworth Since `cmd.exe` is a valid command and doesn't return an error if it doesn't like the string you pass to it the return value and `GetLastError()` would have shown success.

Comment: @Noah On a side note, your `normToWide()` implementation is not the correct way to convert a `std::string` to a `std::wstring`. The logic will only work for ASCII characters. Non-ASCII characters will get corrupted. You need a proper conversion, such as via `MultiByteToWideChar()` or equivalent.

Comment: If you need to ping a server you could call one of the [`IcmpSendEcho`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/icmpapi/nf-icmpapi-icmpsendecho) functions. Far better error reporting, and far more robust than trying to parse text output from *ping.exe*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `ping` is not a built in command in `cmd.exe` and it will not automatically execute the command you pass to it, thus `ping` even if it is installed and in the command path will not be executed. To fix this you have two choices.

The first is to prefix the command string with the `/C` option which *"Carries out the command specified by string and then terminates"* like so

```
/C ping 127.9 -l 4 -n 300 > output.txt
```

This will force `cmd.exe` to execute `ping` if it is in installed and in the command path.

The second is just as easy - just specify `ping.exe` as the command for `ShellExecute` to execute instead of `cmd.exe`.

```
ShellExecute(0, L"open", L"ping.exe", normToWide(command).c_str(), 0, SW_HIDE);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute `ping.exe` and capture the output it produces, it'll be much cleaner to use something on this order:

```cpp
FILE *f = _popen("ping 127.9 -l 4 -n 300"); 
char buffer[256]; 

while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), f) { 
    // `buffer` contains a line of output from `ping`
}
```

Answer (score -2):

ShellExecute(NULL,NULL,L"cmd.exe", L"/K ping 127.9 -l 4 -n 300 > d://test.txt",NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);

/k: end cmd window does not disappear
/c: end cmd window  disappear